# Wxpython clear widgets and create new layout

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a simple game using Wxpyhon. The first layout is the "Welcome!" layout, where users click the "Let's get started! -->" widget button to continue. I want the second layout to have users input their name.

How do I make the first layout change to the second layout (reset to a new a layout)? Do I destroy the Frame or do I destroy the Panel? I want both layouts to be on the same window with the same size, same exact position etc. If I were to destroy the Frame, won't I have to reset and type in the size, position etc again?
Is there any way to do this without using the Hide() widget, WizardPage or AddPage?

I considered making a class or a function that specifically creates a new Frame or Panel everytime the previous one was destroyed so I wouldn't have to go through the trouble of typing in the sizes and positions again, but I don't think this idea will work.

I am very new to Wxpython and Python, for I just started Python more or less a month ago, and I just learned WxPython for around a week. I searched tutorials to help me solve this problem, but I'm still confused on what to put in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jaine, is there a reason why you want to use the same dialog/panel? It is much simpler to have either wxWizard or use 2 different dialog for that. You just overthinking the design.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to destroy anything. You can just hide and show the panels as needed. I have an example of switching between panels on my [blog](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/). Here is the code:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib


class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)


class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(25,12)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Panel Switcher Tutorial")

        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
        self.panel_two.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        switch_panels_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 
                                                  "Switch Panels", 
                                                  "Some text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSwitchPanels, 
                  switch_panels_menu_item)
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    def onSwitchPanels(self, event):
        """"""
        if self.panel_one.IsShown():
            self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
            self.panel_one.Hide()
            self.panel_two.Show()
        else:
            self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
            self.panel_one.Show()
            self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can do the same thing with your application.

Comment: (s)he wrote: `but I don't think this idea will work`. I would be very curious to know why? This is exactly the reason why I asked the question above.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to say unless OP clarifies what they want